# Python code error when trying to use gps on raspberry pi

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I am trying to make a robot and am following a tutorial I found online.
When I got to setting up the gps I set it all up right and when I ran the gps client. cgps -s it worked and it found a connection!

However I followed the rest of the tutorial and it wanted me to make the gps daemon start on system startup and then use python gps to make a log file that I could then import into google maps or earth. I used the code it said and here is my errors.

Here is my python code used in the program:

```
from gps import *
import time
import threading

f = open("locations.csv", "w")

gpsd = None
class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    global gpsd
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
    self.current_value = None
    self.running = True

  def run(self):
    global gpsd
    while gpsp.running:
      gpsd.next()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpsp = GpsPoller()
    try:
      gpsp.start()
      while True:
          f.write(str(gpsd.fix.longitude)
          + "," + str(gpsd.fix.latitude)
          + "\n")
          time.sleep(30)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
      f.close()
      gpsp.running = False
      gpsp.join()
```

Here is the error I get when I run that program, the program is name gps.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 9, in <module>
    class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
  File "gps.py", line 23, in GpsPoller
    gpsp = GpsPoller()
  File "/home/pi/Robot/gps.py", line 13, in __init__
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
NameError: global name 'gps' is not defined
```

Comment: [Make sure you haven’t named your file “gps.py” otherwise python can’t import the gps.py library](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/#comment-608).